# Network Manager keeps creating new profiles for the same network

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I have a problem on my thinkpad t440p with ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
At home, I have two networks:

- one default network
- the extended version of my default network.

When I switch connections (for example from the default to the extended one)
the network manager keeps asking for a password. When I fill it in (with remember this password for all users checked), the network manager creates a new configuration (and does this every time when I reconnect to a network). So I think the network manager thinks I am connecting to a new network when in reality I am connecting to the same one. He then proceeds to create a new configuration for the 'new' network. I never had this problem before and I never changed my router configuration.

EDIT: I can change my network without the network manager asking for a password or adding a new network profile by changing it through the settings (network section).

Answer (score 1):

After searching for a couple of days, I finally found the solution!

Open your terminal and type in the following.

```
sudo nautilus
```

This will open your file manager with root permission.

Go to the following location with your file manager:

/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections

Delete all networks located in this folder.

(there were some networks in this folder that were not shown by the network manager, deleting everything fixed my problem)

After that just restart your pc.

**All your saved network connections will be deleted but the problem will disappear.**